# Intent filter pathPrefix with '#' not working

Tags: android, android-activity, intentfilter

I'm trying to set an intent filter to launch my activity when user clicks on the following URI:
example.com/pathA/pathB/#pathC/someGUID

so I've added the following XML to the manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/pathA/pathB/#pathC"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

I'm thinking that the '#' char is messing everthing up but I've tried escaping this char with no luck. Any ideas?

UPDATE: when I said "tried escaping" I meant using percent encoding (# equals %23)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Intent filters use [UriMatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html) to parse URIs and determine if there is a match. `#` is the URI wildcard for a number as seen in examples in [UriMatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html). Per the [UriMatcher source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/UriMatcher.java), there is no escape sequence to escape a `#` in a URI. Therefore you should use another, non-reserved symbol (note that `*` is also reserved as the wildcard for any text).

Comment: @user1774914 - right - there just doesn't seem to be a way of handling a URI with a `#` in it. You could certainly handle `/pathA/pathB/` and manually check the remainder of the URI for `#pathC`, but that it will appear to the system that you also handle a URI like `/pathA/pathB/pathD`

Comment: The strange thing is that the android docs say... Because '\' is used as an escape character when the string is read from XML (before it is parsed as a pattern), you will need to double-escape: For example, a literal '*' would be written as "\\*" and a literal '\' would be written as "\\\\". This is basically the same as what you would need to write if constructing the string in Java code.

Comment: This would lead you to believe that you could escape the it like \\# , but this still doesn't work.  I guess it's just a no go.

Comment: *2 years later* Did you find a way to figure this out ? Should we really hack this by checking the URL at app code and if it doesn't match the desired pattern we just open browser ?

Comment: There's been no change in intent filter parsing

Comment: Trying the same thing here. No luck :(