# Use hash mark (#) in pathprefix to match intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a URL, https://app.inetrack.com/#home.

In my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.FirstLoginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="https"
              android:host="app.inetrack.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/#home"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

How can I set the pathprefix to match this URL? It works only without the hashmark. Is it possible to escape it somehow?

I tried to escape it like here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path

Comment: Answer could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451162/intent-filter-pathprefix-with-not-working