# Android pathPattern escape #

Tags: android, url, intentfilter

I want to open app after click on link in email.

Something like this: `http://exaple.com/#/recipe/some`

Inside intent-filter in manifest I use this code:

```
<data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*/recipe/.*" />
```

It works fine for any prefix, except symbol `#`. For example,

`http://example.com/any_word/recipe/some`

Is it any way to escape (skip) `#` symbol ?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451162/intent-filter-pathprefix-with-not-working

Comment: As I have understood, it`s impossible.

Comment: Is it possible to support other symbols like - ?