# Deep link for url with hashtag does not work

Tags: android, deep-linking

I would like to add deep link to my Android app for an url with this pattern: `http://myapp.com/#/shows/all`

I have tried the following, which doesn't work, because of the hashtag `/#` in between

```
<data
 android:host="myapp.com"
 android:pathPrefix="/shows/all"
 android:scheme="http" />
```

How to handle this hashtag `/#`?

Comment: `#` character is a special uri delimiter. It delimits the query parameters and the hash. There is no support for this on the Android side. You simply cannot use such pathPrefix here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent filter pathPrefix with '#' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451162/intent-filter-pathprefix-with-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

check these two link's:

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app#add-intent-filters-for-http-urls

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test#testing-urls-with-android-studio

hope it may helps

Comment: Hey, I want to open my app only when url contains particular path /shows/all .

Comment: ya even i done that but in between # tag on URL i never seen make sure with your URL