# Why android does not handle a deeplink url which has # in the path

Tags: android, url, uri, deep-linking, deeplink

The url http://javaexample.com/#/topics is a valid url?

I am try to deeplink the above url in the app using:

```
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="javaexample.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/#/topics" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but the terminal throwing message -

Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://javaexample.com/...

is url http://javaexample.com/#/topics is not a valid url if it has # in the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` in a URL indicates the beginning of the [fragment component](http://uri.thephpleague.com/4.0/components/overview/), which cannot be used for deep link criteria. Even though you've structured the fragment to *look* like a normal URL path to human eyes, the computer does not read it this way.

You'll need to reformat your URLs not to include any `#` character before the path.

Comment: A single page web app decides which part/fragment to display based on the fragment id - which comes after #. 

So a deeplink from hyperlink to web app or in browser (if app is not installed on mobile) will work correctly but if app is installed on mobile how we can achieve the deeplink with same url having # in the path. Should we provide alternative deeplink url for mobile ? Like - if mobile app - then takes alternative url otherwise use the main url? How we can achieve alternate url implementation ?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it. [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) can help with that, since your deep link URLs are then completely separate from your web app. You could also rework your web app to use a different URL construction. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451162/intent-filter-pathprefix-with-not-working) for additional details on why `#` doesn't work.