# Unmatched deep-link in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, deep-linking, ionic3

I'm apps flow goes like this:

1. Launch App
2. Spotify 'Allow App Access' page is opened in the browser (Chrome),
3. The user give the app permission and is redirect to https://appurl.com/spotify-callback/,
4. That URL is deep-linked so that my app is now opened again,
5. The deep-link plugin should now match `/spotify-callback/` and open the page named SpotifyCallbackPage should be opened but I get the error `console.error: Got a deeplink that didn't match`

My deep-link code looks like:

```js
deeplinks.route({
                '/spotify-callback/': SpotifyCallbackPage
            }).subscribe((match) => {
                // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
                // match.$args - the args passed in the link
                // match.$link - the full link data
                console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
            }, (nomatch) => {
                // nomatch.$link - the full link data
                console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match');
                console.log(nomatch);
            });
```

The URL sent to the router is:

```
https://appurl.com/spotify-callback/#access_token=random-access-token-here&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

The full error message is:

```
error opening ws message: {"category":"console","type":"log","data":["On deep 
            link",{"url":"https://appurl.com/spotify-callback/#access_token=random-access-token-here&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600","path":"/spotify-callback/","scheme":"https","host":"appurl.com","fragment":"access_token=random-access-token-here&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600","extra":{"org.chromium.chrome.browser.eenp":["io.ionic.starter"],"org.chromium.chrome.browser.referrer_id":21,"com.android.browser.application_id":"com.android.chrome"}}]}
[16:28:02]  console.error: Got a deeplink that didn't match
```

I've tried different URLs and endpoints in the router but none of them will match. Does anybody know what I should be trying to match?

Comment: I seem to have the same problem, did you manage to fix this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238121/why-android-does-not-handle-a-deeplink-url-which-has-in-the-path could also be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you already have found a way to fix this problem. Perhaps you could try changing the `route url` (spotify-callback) to something like:

`spotify-callback` + [window.location.hash](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)