# pathpattern in intent-filter doesn't match '#!'

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, intentfilter

How can i filter this URl in the intent-filter to open app on clicking on it: 
https://www.host.com/something#!something

it seem '#' is reserved as a wildcard in UriMatcher that pathpattern work with due to @ianhanniballake in this post:
[Intent filter pathPrefix with '#' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451162/intent-filter-pathprefix-with-not-working)

i couldn't either filter it with '!' like this:

```
<data
      android:host="www.host.com"
      android:pathPattern=".*!.*"
      android:scheme="https" />
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is not part of the path of a URL. It is the separator between the path and the fragment (a.k.a., [the fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)). As a result, you cannot filter on it in `pathPattern`. There is no way to filter on a fragment in a `<data>` element. You would need to filter on the rest.

Comment: the only unique characters in this URL is '#' and '!'..any way to filter it with '!' ? @CommonsWare

Comment: @rezandro: That is not possible, sorry.

Comment: would you please tell me whats wrong with '!' ? as you said '#' is the fragment identifier not '!'. thanks anyway

Comment: @rezandro: It is part of the fragment. You cannot filter on a fragment.