# Hash mark in universal links in React Native (EXPO)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've got a problem with Deep linking. Example link to my web app: https://example.com/#/create-password/:id
During open this URI, my app doesn't start.

My app.json:

```
"android": {
...
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "autoVerify": true,
          "data": [
            {
                  "scheme": "https",
                  "host": "*example.com",
                  "pathPrefix": "/#/create-password"
                }
              ],
              "category": [
                "BROWSABLE",
                "DEFAULT"
              ]
            }
          ]
    ...
 }
```

When I remove hash mark form app.json and run https://example.com/create-password/:id, my react native app starts.
Could you help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing seems to be directly related to Android not React Native - [Intent filter pathPrefix with '#' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451162/intent-filter-pathprefix-with-not-working). I suppose you can work around that using `pathPattern` instead of `pathPrefix`.